# How do I use this Python package? (guess_language)

Tags: python, package, wiki

I am trying to use this package: http://pypi.python.org/pypi/guess-language/0.1
I've read the documentation/wiki, but can't find the solution.

Basically, this package allows you to pass in a string, and it will return a "language".
I'm able to make it print out "en".

```
htmlSource = download('http://feeds.feedburner.com/nchild')
soup = BeautifulStoneSoup(htmlSource)
justwords = ''.join(soup.findAll(text=True))
justwords = justwords.encode('utf-8')
true_lang =  guess_language.guessLanguage(justwords)
```

I'd like to know...how does this person print out the scores/accuracy of the guess?

[Am I passing the string correctly to the python library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2164899/am-i-passing-the-string-correctly-to-the-python-library/2165936#2165936)

Comment: "This person" has now given you the obvious(?) answer in the 3rd update to his answer of your original question. I suggest that you delete this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By modifying the source code of the module, from the sounds of this quote (taken from the answer you linked to):

> Update after some experimentation, *including inserting a print statement to show what script blocks were detected with what percentages*

(Emphasis added by me.)